# Watchpoint doesn't work when reverse executing

Tags: c, gdb, x86-64, watchpoint

Here's a debugging scenario:

1. Create start breakpoint **A** and finish breakpoint **B**.
2. Start recording. Continue.
3. Reach breakpoint **B**.
4. Set watchpoint to watch writes to some piece of memory.
5. Reverse continue until watchpoint breaks execution.

Let's suppose that setting the watchpoint is only possible in step 4, not earlier, since the location of memory that should be watched is only known at that point.

Here's a simple example.
main.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    num = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Debugging session:

```
$ cc main.c
$ gdb -q -nx -ex 'set disassembly-flavor intel' ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in ./a.out)
(gdb) b *main + 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001129 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000112a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000112d <+4>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
   0x0000000000001134 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001139 <+16>:    pop    rbp
   0x000000000000113a <+17>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *main + 16
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1139
(gdb) r
Starting program: /var/tmp/test/a.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555129 in main ()
(gdb) record
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555555139 in main ()
(gdb) p/x $rbp-0x4
$1 = 0x7fffffffe63c
(gdb) watch *(int*)0x7fffffffe63c
Hardware watchpoint 3: *(int*)0x7fffffffe63c
(gdb) reverse-continue
Continuing.

No more reverse-execution history.
0x0000555555555129 in main ()
(gdb)
```

The last command shows that reverse execution didn't stop where it is supposed to stop, that is `*main+4`. Instead, it stopped where the recording has started, ignoring any memory writes.

My simple experiment was motivated by [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PorfLSr3DDI&t=550s) video at the *CppCon 2015*, highlighting usefulness of the record & replay concept. Really, I don't know what I've done wrong, because for me it seems that I've repeated every step from the video.

Also, reading [gdb docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) didn't help either.

So, why the watchpoint has been ignored and how can it be prevented?

Comment: I don't suppose it matters that you have a PIE executable, so absolute addresses of code aren't known until after the program starts (e.g. with `starti` to stop before the first user-space instruction).  Despite using `b *main + 0` and GDB reporting `Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129`, it still stopped at `0x0000555555555129` after you ran the program.  I was worried about the use of `*main`.  But that doesn't seem to be the problem, and you set the watchpoint after the program was running (so the stack frame existed).

Comment: Perhaps the *hardware* watchpoint is the problem, since it would be GDB changing values in memory, not execution of the process itself?  Can you tell GDB to use a software watchpoint?  IIRC, it will do that when you use an expression that isn't always the contents of the same absolute address, but IDK how to get it to do that when you are watching an absolute address

Comment: It looks like hardware watchpoints don't work at all if recording, no matter which direction you try to continue. At least it's like this on my end with gdb 10 and 11.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the suggestion. I've tested with the *software* watchpoint and it worked. And your remark about gdb changing values in memory instead of real process execution is a pretty logical explanation why *hardware* watchpoints don't work. BTW, you can force gdb to use software watchpoints even with absolute addresses by `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0`.

Comment: According to the video, this apparently worked with hardware watchpoints in gdb 7.7.1, so maybe you want to create a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Try telling *gdb* to use a **software** breakpoint instead of the **hardware** one through the command `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0`.

It seems that the **hardware** watchpoint doesn't work here because when executing back and forth through *reverse-execution history*, no traditional process execution takes place, it's only `gdb` changing it's internal memory to make appearance that a program executed backwards.

In other words, we should use **hardware** watchpoints when the real process executes on a CPU, and **software** watchpoints when `gdb` makes an emulation through its recording history.

Thanks to *Peter Cordes* for the explanation in the comments.